# What causes 3 special characters after conversion to UTF-8?

Tags: conversion, notepad++, utf-8, ultraedit

One of our work steps involves saving an MS Excel worksheet as CSV and then using UltraEdit to convert the CSV to UTF-8 before importing it into a server system.

**The problem is** that, after the conversion to UTF-8, the file always contains 3 nonsense characters at the start of the file:

> ï»¿ENTITY_ID;FIELD2;FIELD3,FIELD4;(etc.)
>   value1;value2;value3;value4;(etc).

**Observations:**

- As you can see, there are 3 characters that are noise and cause the server to reject the CSV import because the first column is not named "ENTITY_ID". The characters are always the same.
- These characters are not shown after the conversion, but when we close and reopen the file in UltraEdit again, then we do see the characters.
- These characters are only visible in UltraEdit. Windows Notepad or Notepad++ does not show them.
- Using Notepad++ to convert the CSV to UTF-8 produces the exact same output: a file with the same 3 odd characters in the beginning. The only difference is that Notepad++ does not display these characters, even after closing and reopening the file.

**Workaround:**
We reopen the file in UltraEdit, delete the noise, and then the server accepts the CSV import.
This step needs to be eliminated by fixing the actual problem.

***Question:* How can we avoid these 3 characters?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), encoded as UTF-8. Tell your editor to not add it at the beginning, or use a real decoder in your server system.

Comment: Thank you! This prompted [another question](http://superuser.com/questions/379791/how-to-make-ultraedit-save-in-utf-8-without-bom), of course :-)