# How to make UltraEdit save in UTF-8 without the byte order mark (BOM)?

Tags: utf-8, ultraedit

[This related post](https://superuser.com/questions/379780/what-causes-3-special-characters-after-conversion-to-utf-8) tells me that UltraEdit adds the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) when UTF-8-encoding files.

How can I make UltraEdit **convert a file into UTF-8 without adding the byte order mark?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ultraedit website says -

> If you'd like to globally configure UltraEdit to save all UTF-8 files
>   with BOMs, you can set this by going to Advanced -> Configuration ->
>   File Handling -> Save. The first two options here, "Write UTF-8 BOM
>   header to all UTF-8 files when saved" and "Write UTF-8 BOM on new
>   files created within this program (if above is not set)" should be
>   checked. Conversely, if you do NOT want the BOMs, make sure these are
>   NOT checked.

[Source](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/unicode.html)

Comment: I've tested this and confirm it works!!

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a file that already has a BOM in it and need to save it without the BOM, then choose  *File* -> *Save As* and in the *Format* drop-down box, choose *UTF-8 - NO BOM*.

This will remain the default 'save' format for all other files as long as your version of UltraEdit is greater than v17.10.0.1015 (there was a bug in UltraEdit prior to this where the 'save as' format was not remembered).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if you tell UE to create new files as UTF8, it will be saved with BOM so it's a good idea to check on it at the first "Save As" operation.  (Very annoying, if you ask me.)